# C# how to convert ionic ZipFile to Stream or bytes, and then ZipFile

Tags: c#, zip, memorystream

I need to modify a Controller of existing Web API. The controller has three methods, and I want to combine them (A,B, and C). Each method uses a common method that returns ionic ZipFile. 
The method A returns zipfile1, the method B returns zipfile2, and the methodC returns zipfile3. But now zipfile3 does not need anymore and C needs to return the contents of zipfile1 and zipfile2 into only one zipfile which is the goal of this question.

The common method first retrieves file contents from DB by loop, add the contents to zipfile using `AddEntry`, and returns zipfile. Each zipfile has its own folder structure.

I am thinking the **return type** from the common method is the key. and personally think there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Make the return type of the common method **ZipFile** and convert the returned zipfile to byte and then stream, then add to the zipfile in **C**.(see idea1 image)
2. Make the return type of the common method **MemoryStream** and add to the zipfile in **C**.(see idea2 image)

The idea2 sounds better than the idea1 because it eliminates some steps that are converting zipfile to byte to sream.

what I tried:

- Idea1, but when I excecute the program, and could download zipfile saying 400kb. But when I extract it, it has the folder structure but is actually empty. I guess the step of the converting zipfile to byte to stream is wrong but do not get it right.
- Idea2, I could get return type as stream and could download the zipfile from C, but it does not have the specified folder structure and contents.

My questions are:

1. Which idea is better for this situation?
2. For Idea1, what am I wrong when converting zipfile to byte, and stream? Why the downloaded zipfile does not have contents?
3. For Idea2, how do I return stream having the folder structure?
4. What concept have I been missing?

[Idea1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwcFq.png)

[Idea2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hBJL.png)

Comment: 1) You are probably talking about the Ionic.Zip library; this has nothing to do with the "Ionic SDK" to which the tag "ionic2" refers. 2) Do you want the resulting ZIP file to contain the merged structure of the input ZIP files; or shall the resulting ZIP file contain the two original ZIP files are its only content?

Comment: @KlausGütter I removed the tag. I was gonna tag Ionic but accidentally did it. I want to two folders in the resulting zipfile. and the each folder has its own folder structure meaning I do not want merge the folder structure. I want to store the two folders without zip into one parent folder with zip.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to do the following: given two input ZIPs with structure

```
a.ZIP
    x.txt
    f/x.txt
b.ZIP
    y.txt
    f/y.txt
=> 
result.zip
    a/x.txt
    a/f/x.txt
    b/y.txt
    b/f/y.txt
```

Because you want to keep the structure of the source zip files, you will have to iterate over all of them and re-create the structure in the result zip.

This could be done as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var resultZip = new ZipFile())
  {
    foreach (var zipFileName in args)
    {
      using (var inputZip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName))
      {
        Add(resultZip, inputZip, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFileName));
      }
    }
    resultZip.Save("all.zip");
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Merge the complete content of <paramref name="inputZip"/> to <paramref name="resultZip"/>, preserving the folded structure
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resultZip">The ZIP file to merge to</param>
/// <param name="inputZip">The ZIP file to merge from</param>
/// <param name="folder">The folder name in <paramref name="resultZip"/> where the content should be put, or null for the root.</param>
private static void Add(ZipFile resultZip, ZipFile inputZip, string folder)
{
  foreach (var inputEntry in inputZip.Entries)
  {
    using (var inputStream = inputEntry.OpenReader())
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
      var resultFileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder) ? inputEntry.FileName : folder + "/" + inputEntry.FileName;
      resultZip.AddEntry(resultFileName, memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
  }
}
```

The code iterates over all entries of the source ZIP file, reads the content into a `MemoryStream` and then adds the entry to the output ZIP. The file name in the output ZIP is constructed here from the file name of the input ZIP plus the name in the input ZIP.

In your case, where you do not get ZIP file names as input, but the ZipFile objects themselves, you can still use the Add method above, but might have a different means of determining the folder parameter.